# Wny is the loss during fitting of a Tensorflow Probabilistic model always ```nan```

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, tensorflow-probability

I am working on a Tensorflow *probabilistic* model to recognize digits in the MNIST dataset.
I am encountering the problem that during fitting of the model, it always reports the
loss to be `nan`.  Here is the definition of the loss function:

```
def nll(y_true, y_pred):
    # This function should return the negative log-likelihood of each sample
    # in y_true given the predicted distribution y_pred.
    result =  - y_pred.log_prob( y_true )
    return result
```

Here's the code that generates and compiles the model:

```
def get_probabilistic_model(input_shape, loss, optimizer, metrics):
    # This function should return the compiled probabilistic model
    model = Sequential([
        Conv2D( filters = 8, kernel_size = ( 5, 5 ), activation = "relu", padding = "valid", input_shape = input_shape ),
        MaxPooling2D( pool_size = ( 6, 6 ) ),
        Flatten(),
        Dense( units = 10, activation = None ),
        tfpl.DistributionLambda( lambda t:  tfd.OneHotCategorical( probs = t ) )
    ])
    model.compile( loss = loss, optimizer = optimizer, metrics = metrics )
    return model

tf.random.set_seed(0)
probabilistic_model = get_probabilistic_model(
    input_shape=(28, 28, 1), 
    loss=nll, 
    optimizer=RMSprop(), 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

`probabilistic_model.summary()` confirms that the model is being built and compiled
successfully.  However, when I try to fit the model, I get the following:

```
probabilistic_model.fit(x_train, y_train_oh, epochs=5)

Train on 60000 samples
Epoch 1/5
20544/60000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 40s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0978
```

The problem is that the `loss` is `nan` (not a number), and the accuracy seems
quite small, not surprising given that the loss is messed up.

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with either the definition of the loss
function, or the construction / compilation of the model, or what.

Comment: have you tried another loss function and see what happens?

Comment: You need `tfpl.OneHotCategorical(num_classes)` for the last layer. `OneHotCategorical` already inherits from `DistributionLambda`.

Comment: @Frightera, THANKS!  changing the ```DistributionLambda``` to ```tfpl.OneHotCategorical(num_classes) ``` worked; the loss and accuracy look reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

From comments

> You need `tfpl.OneHotCategorical(num_classes)` for the last layer.
> `OneHotCategorical` already inherits from `DistributionLambda` (paraphrased from Frightera)